# NSPredicate checking certain String

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring, nspredicate, predicatewithformat

I m working on a code which was implemented by someone else which is as follows

```
+(BOOL)emailValidate:(NSString *)email  {
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 
return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
}

+(BOOL) IDValidate:(NSString *)ID {
NSString *regexString = @"[ A-Z0-9a-z_+-]{1,20}"; 
NSPredicate *regex = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regexString]; 
return [regex evaluateWithObject:ID];
}
```

I want to alow spaces " " and commas "," in ID and email, I search a lot how to alter predicateFormat but could not find the answer.

Comment: I'll add this, if you're checking a list of mail addresses (that's the only way of "allowing comas and space in mail" I thought about), a solution could be to delete all space (`stringByReplacingString:withString:`) and using `componentsSeparatedByString` (with the coma) and check each one of them. With this, you may be even able to tell which address doesn't fit.

Comment: Yes, this trick will work but not recommended way as when system give you support for something, then why to do it for yourself,

Comment: Well, the use of what I suggested is to tell user which address exactly doesn't fit, info that isn't returned with an "all in one" `NSPredicate` suggested by Mohammad Imran. That's just in case, this use case could interests you (or another member of SO) since it should work ass well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, `Coma (,)` is not allowed in email. But for your scenario, Use following regular expression:

```
For "xyx,+ xyz125"
  ^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9,+_- ]+$
For email
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

Hopefully will solve you problem.

Comment: Thank, I need this function for other field not email, where text allow comma and space as well. I try to reuse the code but could not understand the string pattern.

Comment: great solution by imran you are genius.